# Ошибка подключения клиента к серверу. Сокеты Python

Tags: python, сокет

При подключении  клиента к серверу возникает ошибка:
`ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]` Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
Язык Python
Сначала запускаю сервер и только после пытаюсь подключить клиента.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой причине может возникать такая ситуация?

---

SocketServer.ру

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind (('127.0.0.1',65530))
client = []  # Массив где храним адреса клиентов
print ('Start Server')
while 1 :
         data , address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
         print (address[0], address[1])
         if  address not in client : 
                 client.append(address)  # Если такова клиента нету , то добавить
         for clients in client :
                 if clients == address: 
                     continue  # Не отправлять данные клиенту который их прислал
                 sock.sendto(data, clients)
```

---

SocketClient.ру

```
import socket


s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 65530

s.connect((host, port))
```

Comment: Например, по причине работающего брендмаура на windows ОС `WinError 10061` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437701/winerror-10061-no-connection-could-be-made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы используете `UDP` протокол (`socket.SOCK_DGRAM`), который не поддерживает создания соединения, поэтому `s.connect((host, port))` и выдаёт Вам ошибку. Советую почитать про [`TCP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) и [`UDP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP), а ещё лучше хотя бы поверхностно изучить стек протоколов [`TCP/IP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP) (если хотите изучить сети более углублённо, то есть очень хороший курс на хабре [Сети для самых маленьких](https://habr.com/ru/post/134892/)).

---

Для решения проблемы

- Либо используйте `TCP` сокет на сервере:

```py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

И используйте соответствующие методы (`listen`, `recv` и т.д.)

- Либо не пытайтесь создать соединение с клиента. Вместо этого можете сразу отправлять байты на сервер:

```py
# s.connect((host, port))
s.sendto(b"some data", (host, port))
```